# Multiple optionals key value in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

With vue-router I need to create a route which can handles multiple optional parameters.
For example I need a route which can handles:

> ```
> /something/a/1/b/2/c/3
> /something/a/1/b/2
> /something/a/1/c/3
> /something/b/2/c/3
> /something/a/1
> /something/b/2
> /something/c/3
> /something/
> ```

Letters are the key and digits are the relative value.

Actually I *coded* something like this

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        { path: '/something/a/:a/b/:b/c/:c', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/a/:a/b/:b', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/a/:a/c/:c', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/b/:b/c/:c', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/a/:a', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/b/:b', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/c/:c', component: MyComponent },
        { path: '/something/', component: MyComponent },
    ]
})
```

Is possible to accomplish this using a regex? Maybe can I just use `'/something/*'` then extract parameters later?
By the way values are all ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js) I found out I can use parenthesis and `?` to make a path optional in this way

> /path/(foo/)?bar

BUT if you wrap parenthesis with the param too `/path/(foo/:foo)?` the param name will be literal interpreted as part of URI (in this example as `:foo`) so only the routes `/path/` and `/path/foo/:foo` (`:foo` is literal in the URI not a parameter!) will works.

So I thought to use regex instead of a simple `/something/*`.
I used as regex `/something/(a/\\d+)?/(b/\\d+)?/(c/\\d+)?` (`\\d+` is the regex for digits but you can use any regex here).

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    base: __dirname,
    routes: [
        { path: '/something/(a/\\d+)?/(b/\\d+)?/(c/\\d+)?', component: MyComponent },
    ]
})
```

Then the values obtained in `this.$route.params` in a URI like `/something/a/5/b/6/c/7` will be

```
{ 1: "b/6", 2: "c/7", pathMatch: "a/5" }
```

If a value is not set it will be `undefined`.

```
// /something/a/5/c/7
{ 1: undefined, 2: "c/7", pathMatch: "a/5" }
```

Now in `MyComponent` I edited `this.$route.params` to make it looks better

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.$route.params);
        if (this.$route.params.pathMatch) {
            let res = this.$route.params.pathMatch.split("/");
            this.$route.params[res[0]] = res[1];
        }
        delete this.$route.params.pathMatch;
        if (this.$route.params[1]) {
            let res = this.$route.params[1].split("/");
            this.$route.params[res[0]] = res[1];
        }
        delete this.$route.params[1];
        if (this.$route.params[2]) {
            let res = this.$route.params[2].split("/");
            this.$route.params[res[0]] = res[1];
        }
        delete this.$route.params[2];
        console.log(this.$route.params);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can do better this second part (for example instead of `res[0]` you can write the expected key or you can do everything in iterative way) but it works

```
{ a: "5" b: "6", c: "7" }
```

Comment: Good, i will try it in full example when i have enough time